# Search multiple databases

Tags: search

Running a website on Drupal 6.

I'm currently using Faceted Search to search the default database for the website.

I've installed a separate Knowledgebase application (KB Publisher) which has it's own database and search, but I would like to use one search box (the default website search box) to index/search BOTH the default website database & the Knowledgebase database.

I'm not really a hard core programmer and am looking for some ideas/assistance in doing this?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any easy solution exits. But you can connect to another database by adding below lines into your settings.php file.

$db_url['mydb'] = 'mysql://user:pwd@localhost/anotherdb';

and use [db_set_active()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.inc/function/db_set_active/6) function in appropriate places to query other database while your existing database index. You may need to have a deep look in to the Search module for that.

Comment: Thanks, in Drupal 6 can you query multiple databases at the same time?

Comment: Sure you can with the db_set_active(EXTERNAL) prior to querying the external database.

Comment: Thanks...I'll have to hash this out in my DEV environment. Fingers crossed!